# REST API Wrapper in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I am aware of that, writing RESTful APIs would be easier and secure using some framework. There are already existing RESTful APIs of several 3rd parties. I need to develop RESTful APIs in Python which accepts request in JSON format, validates the request data and behind the scenes call the 3rd party APIs via CURL and sends the response received back to to the consumer in JSON format. 
I have been able to do it in PHP using Codeigniter Framework.

Can anyone please provide suggestions on how to proceed for it, some tutorials link, best framework to move with.

Have shortlisted 3 frameworks,

1) Django REST Framework

Prerequisites - Knowledge of Django Framework (Obtained Just enough knowledge)

2) Bottle Framework (Micro framework) -
Explored a bit

3) Flask Framework (Micro framework) -
Yet not explored

Please note, I am having a very small learning curve of just about 5 days.

Please help.

Comment: Use Flask in my opinion. There are numerous packages to choose from... flask-restful, flask-restplus, you can even build a rest api onto an existing Flask web app that uses the @app.route decorators.. You can add endpoints/restful routes just like they were HTML pages, except they return JSON responses... There are very little restrictions with Flask which is why I like it the best

Comment: Pretty much Flask - Django is overkill for such task. Add flask-restful to get all API requirements.

Comment: @Gasanov Can you provide a tutorial/video tutorial link to get started without wasting much of the time in overview sort of stuff

Comment: @sit_on_a_pan_otis Can you provide a tutorial/video tutorial link to get started without wasting much of the time in overview sort of stuff

Comment: @vraj If you have general knowledge of python, just go for [official flask quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) and [official flask-restful quickstart](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html). Do not get into hard details on flask - some parts of it will not be useful for you (such as templating and static files). You will also need to know about `requests` [module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to send requests to 3rd party API.

Comment: This guy's videos are pretty good... https://youtu.be/CjYKrbq8BCw There's a few he did that I watched a while back that were of big help

Comment: @Gasanov. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sit_on_a_pan_otis. Thanks a lot.